# Laravel Relationship with OR case

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, model, relationships

Assume I have a User model, and also I have Couple model which forms of 2 users, `father_id` and `mother_id` which are essentially `user_ids`

On User model, I have

```
public function kids() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Kid', 'father_id');
}
```

However, I want to check if `user_id` is either `father_id` or `mother_id`, return the related Kid model.

Is there a way to achieve it with a single relationship? What is the proper way of handling this scenario, so I can use `$user->kids` that would check for both cases?

Comment: I don't think Laravel has any solution for you.  I'd rethink your relationship, using a simple parent to child many-to-many rather than two one to many relationships.  If you want to describe a parent as a father, do so in the pivot/intermediate table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way, but you wouldn't typically use it to "check" if there are related models.

If you have a field that determines if the model is representing a father or mother, such as is_father, you could do:

```
public function kids()
{
    return ($this->is_father)
        ? $this->hasMany(Kid::class, 'father_id')
        : $this->hasMany(Kid::class, 'mother_id');
}
```

Essentially, the relationship method MUST return a relationship instance. But you can do logic before you return this.

**NOTE:** The relationship is cached, so even if the is_father value changes in the same thread run, it will utilize the same relationship that it did before. This can cause unwanted bugs.